# Best way to learn Racket Macro system for imperative style programmers

Tags: racket

What is the best route for an experienced imperative style programmer only familiar with C macros to learn the Racket macro system.  Not just the mechanics of it (the how?) but also the where and why to use it and examples that illustrate this.

Should one learn Scheme (or Lisp) macros first?  I've heard that the book "On Lisp" has a good explanation of Lisp macros with excellent examples of their use.  Would this be useful or not?

Comment: This question was asked 3 years ago, and got two good answers. I don't see why placing it "on hold" was useful, especially since the people placing it "on hold" don't have any experience in this area.

Comment: That's what I was wondering Sam :-)

Comment: Harry, you should vote to re-open this question.

Comment: I just noticed it was closed because I got a notice that it now passed a thousand hits.  That's more than for any of my other questions.  How do I call for a vote to re-open

Comment: Harry, several other people already voted to re-open, so it's open again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Racket's documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/) has an [excellent tutorial on using macros](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/macros.html).

I would definitely recommend Scheme macros over CL macros if you haven't deal with any sort of Lisp macros before. That's because Scheme macros use pattern matching, and it's much easier to read.

Example (using Racket's `define-syntax-rule`):

```
(define-syntax-rule (let ((var val) ...)
                      expr ...)
  ((lambda (var ...)
     expr ...)
   val ...))
```

This is a very simple macro that defines `let` in terms of creating a corresponding lambda, then applying it. It's easy to read, and easy to reason about what it does.

Slightly more complicated macro:

```
(define-syntax let*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((let* ()
       expr ...)
     (let ()
       expr ...))
    ((let* ((var val) next ...)
       expr ...)
     (let ((var val))
       (let* (next ...)
         expr ...)))))
```

This defines `let*` in terms of nested `let`s, so that the bindings are done sequentially. It includes a base case (with no bindings), as well as a recursive case.

Comment: Can you recommend any books for this.

Comment: Don't know about books, but Racket has an excellent guide for macros: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/macros.html

Comment: You should update the answer with this pointer, since it's a more direct answer to the original question...

Comment: I have just found Ryan Culpepper's dissertation: "Refining Syntactic Sugar: Tools for Supporting Macro Development" with the case studies in chapter 8. http://www.ccs.neu.edu/scheme/pubs/dissertation-culpepper.pdf

Answer (score 12):

I believe that the best tutorial on macros is still Kent Dybvig's ["Writing Hygenic macros in Scheme with `syntax-case`"](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-bin/techreports/TRNNN.cgi?trnum=TR356).  It's not specifically about Racket, but basically everything will carry over, and reading the [guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/macros.html) that Chris mentioned above will cover any remaining differences.  Despite the name, it covers both "hygenic" and "unhygenic" macros.

**Edit July 2014:**

Since I wrote the above, Greg Hendershott has written a fabulous tutorial on macros in Racket, entitled [Fear of Macros](http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/). That's now the best place to start learning about Racket macros.

Comment: +1 for Dybvig's article. I've actually read it a while ago and it helped me understand `syntax-case` macros a lot, especially how things like `with-syntax` worked.